# what type of jQuery effect do I need to accomplish the same thing

Tags: jquery, effect

I would like to know how [this type](http://www.ing.nl/particulier/index.aspx) of slider, where the arrow next to the picture is sliding, could be accomplished with jQuery.
I can see in Firebug that it is made with Flash.

It does not seem to be overly complicated to accomplish it with jQuery, but that´s not saying that I already know how to.

What would be the best way to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would suggest you take a look at the jQuery [animate function](http://docs.jquery.com/Effects/animate) - using this in conjunction with a CSS positioned DIV or image should allow you to do what you want.

Comment: thanks, so that´s basicly how a slider works also, I guess.
Then I know what to google for.

Comment: Yes, you can slide elements quite easily, and there's built in easing, timing etc.

Comment: I was thinking off a slider plugin, but I don´t know what the big advantage would be.

Comment: You don't really need an external plugin for this simple animation - animate() will do everything you need I think.